# PyQt: QTabbleWidget with Undo and Redo Actions

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, undo-redo

So, I'm using Python with PyQt. In my application, I have a QTableWidget. What I notice is that it doesn't keep some sort of "history" for undo and redo. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to track the history yourself. Qt has [Undo Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qundo.html) for that.

Comment: I haven't used myself, but read ["A Practical Introduction to PyQt's Undo/Redo Framework"](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187104)